# How do I add <tr> and complete </tr> tag in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have this kind of array in `$form_all_data` variable.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 111
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 38
            [meta_key] => 6
            [meta_value] => Student 1
            [item_index] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 112
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 38
            [meta_key] => 3
            [meta_value] => Not sure
            [item_index] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 113
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 38
            [meta_key] => 5
            [meta_value] => 55
            [item_index] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 129
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 43
            [meta_key] => 6
            [meta_value] => Student 3
            [item_index] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 130
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 43
            [meta_key] => 3
            [meta_value] => Yes
            [item_index] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 131
            [form_id] => 1
            [entry_id] => 43
            [meta_key] => 5
            [meta_value] => 55
            [item_index] => 
        )

)
```

I am showing all this data inside `<table>`. These entries are differentiated as per `entry_id`.
I want to add `<tr>` tag when every time new `entry_id` is there in the loop and want to complete `</tr>` tag when every time same `entry_id` is last in the loop.

Something like this. Please check this image [image]

This means I want to show `entry_id` **38** data in one `<tr>` and `entry_id` **43** data in another `<tr>`

How can I do this ?

In my code , it is adding `<tr>` with every new iteration

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ( $form_all_data  as $check_form_all_data_key => $check_form_all_data_value ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php
        if ( $check_form_all_data_value->form_id == 1 ) {

            if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 6 ) { ?>
                <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
            <?php }

            if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 3 ) { ?>
                <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
            <?php }

        } else {

        } ?>

    </tr>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: What keeps you from changing the loop?

Comment: I am not getting how do I add/complete `<tr>` conditionally.

Comment: you don't need any condition of some sort, you just need to gather the appropriate data in place. first group everything by `entry_id`, it will line up then as row format. then you can echo each `<tr>` accordingly. to group them, it's the usual key array group assignment `foreach ( $form_all_data  as $k=> $v) {  $new_data[$v['entry_id']] = $v } `

Comment: Thank You @Kevin Your solution works , I didn't realize it was that easy. I just edited bit : `$new_data = array(); foreach ( $form_all_data as $k=> $v ) { $new_data[$v->entry_id][] = $v; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

```
<?php
$form_all_data = [
    (object)['entry_id' => 1, 'value' => '1 1', 'type' => '1'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 1, 'value' => '1 2', 'type' => '2'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 2, 'value' => '2 1', 'type' => '1'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 2, 'value' => '2 2', 'type' => '2'],
];
$currentEntryId = null;
$needCloseTr = false;
echo '<table>';
foreach ($form_all_data as $row) {
    //is next entry?
    if ($currentEntryId !== $row->entry_id) {
        //close previous tr
        if ($needCloseTr) {
            echo '</tr>';
            $needCloseTr = false;
        } else {
            $needCloseTr = true;
        }
        $currentEntryId = $row->entry_id;
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $row->value);
}
//close last tr
if ($needCloseTr) {
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But what you are doing is not correct.
It's better to process the $form_all_data array first and get the data that doesn't need tricky processing, like this:

```
<?php
$form_all_data = [
    (object)['entry_id' => 1, 'value' => '1 1', 'type' => '1'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 1, 'value' => '1 2', 'type' => '2'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 2, 'value' => '2 1', 'type' => '1'],
    (object)['entry_id' => 2, 'value' => '2 2', 'type' => '2'],
];
$result = [];
foreach ($form_all_data as $row) {
    $result[$row->entry_id][$row->type] = $row->value;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution as suggested by  @Kevin

```
<?php

$new_data = array();

foreach ( $form_all_data as $k=> $v ) {  
    $new_data[$v->entry_id][] = $v;
}

foreach ( $new_data as $new_data_key => $new_data_value ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
        foreach ( $new_data_value as $check_form_all_data_key  => $check_form_all_data_value ) { 
            if ( $check_form_all_data_value->form_id == 1 ) {

                if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 6 ) { ?>
                    <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
                <?php }

                if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 3 ) { ?>
                    <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
                <?php }

            } else {

            } ?>


        <?php } ?> 
    </tr> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect entry_id change with as following code

```
<?php
    
        $i = 1;
        $prev_entry_id = 0; 
        foreach ( $form_all_data  as $check_form_all_data_key => $check_form_all_data_value ) { ?>
    
            <?php if($prev_entry_id == 0){
              echo "<tr>";
            }else if($prev_entry_id != $check_form_all_data_value->entry_id){
              echo "</tr><tr>";
            } ?>
                <?php
                if ( $check_form_all_data_value->form_id == 1 ) {
        
                    if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 6 ) { ?>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
                    <?php }
        
                    if ( $check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 3 ) { ?>
                        <td class=""><?php echo $check_form_all_data_value->meta_value ?></td>
                    <?php }
        
                } else {
        
                } ?>
            <? $prev_entry_id = $check_form_all_data_value->entry_id; ?>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
        </tr> // Don't forget this at the end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$rows = [];
foreach ($form_all_data as $row) {
    if (!isset($rows[$row->id])) {
        $rows[$row->id] = [];
    }
    $rows[$row->id][] = $row;
}

$html = '';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        $html .= '<td>'.$cell->meta_value.'</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use switch case for form_id and if clause for meta_key. For example :

```
<?php
    $row = "";
    
    foreach ($form_all_data as $check_form_all_data_key => $check_form_all_data_value)
    {
        $row .= "<tr>";
    
        switch ($check_form_all_data_key->form_id)
        {
            case 1:
                if ($check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 6 || $check_form_all_data_value > meta_key = 3) 
                $row .="<td>".$check_form_all_data_value->meta_value."</td>";
                break;
            case 2:
                if ($check_form_all_data_value->meta_key == 1 || $check_form_all_data_value > meta_key = 5 || $check_form_all_data_value > meta_key = 2)
                $row .="<td>".$check_form_all_data_value->meta_value."</td>";
                break;
            default:
                // more case form_id you want check
                break;
            }
    
            $row .= "</tr>";
        }
    
        echo $row;
    ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: how can i explain more, my variable name show it.

Comment: What is "it"? You could start by highlighting what you've changed, and why these changes are important to resolve the problem